# Best way to prevent unauthorized user on Angular site from seeing site for a split second before being redirected to login?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, authorization, interceptor

I am currently building an Angular front end on a site that pulls much of its data from an API that requires authorization via login.

I have built the following authInterceptor that works well and redirects users to the login page if a 401 error is sent from the server:

```
angular
  .module('myApp.services')
  .factory('authInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$window', '$location', function($rootScope, $q, $window, $location) {

    return {
        'request': function(config) {
          config.headers = config.headers || {};
          if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $window.sessionStorage.token;
          }

          return config;
        },
        'response': function(response) {
          return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function(rejection){
          if (rejection.status == 401){
            $location.path('#/login');
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }

      };
  }])
```

The problem with this is that the API calls and therefore, the 401 errors don't occur until the end of the page load process -  so, users can see a split second of all of the elements (e.g., HTML, CSS, images and all other elements that don't hit the API) loading up on my page before the application hits the API and gets the 401.

I've worked around this by putting a random API call right at the beginning of my MainController that doesn't really do anything but this seems like the wrong way to do it since I'm making an unnecessary ping to the server. Any suggestions and best practices around this?

Also, when I do hit those unauthorized routes, I get the ugly 401 error messages in my console - is there a way to do this redirect without displaying those to the user or is this normal?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea anyway as a user could easily suspend to script from the dev console and just check your website freely. You should have a separate page for login, and if the user is authentified the server serves the regular page.

Comment: Well so the user doesn't actually see anything even if they suspend scripts because all that is loaded is plain HTML and CSS  - all they see is the shell of the app rather than the contents which are loaded up from the API. I do have a separate login page - when a user tries to access '#/dashboard' without authorization, they see a split second shell of the dashboard (elements being loaded up from local development server) before the API call hits and they are redirected to the '#/login' page

Comment: So if your concern is just a "glitch design" problem rather than security breach, you could simply hide the whole body (`display: none` or `opacity: 0`) and then once the user is ok and the page loaded you remove that hidding property. edit: this is exactly what ng-cloak does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a ui-router for your application routing, you could use nested states and a resolve clause in a parent of your 'authenticated' states to make sure that you only get to that controller/template if your 'login' request has successfully resolved and to redirect to a 'sign-in' state if the request fails.

Here is some guidance on how to protect your 'authenticated' routes using ui-router:

[http://blog.john.mayonvolcanosoftware.com/protecting-routes-in-angularjs/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140731154934/http://blog.john.mayonvolcanosoftware.com/protecting-routes-in-angularjs)

Comment: @BrunoPeres 'tis the nature of internet :( updated the link to internet-archived version

Answer (score 2):

I think ng-cloak may help you here as you can add this to elements that should be hidden until your application is bootstrapped, I have done something similar, will try and get you an example